# PostgreSQL node server connecting to local pg rather than cloud (digitalocean)

Tags: node.js, postgresql, digital-ocean

Hi I am trying to connect to Postgres on digital ocean with a node basic server, but every time I hit a api end point like localhost:3001 etc instead of trying to connect to the pg on DO I get connected or try to connect to pg locally.

The credentials and config params all point to the digital ocean pg so I am not sure why is it trying to connect to the local pg on my Mac. I have a M1 Mac.

Another question is do I need pg locally installed to connect to DO pg? I removed the pg locally uninstalling everything and tried to connect to DO pg but it won't work, I get an error:

```
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:5432
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1161:16) {
  errno: -61,
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '127.0.0.1',
  port: 5432
}
```

The reason I am asking is that I have almost exact logic on a electron node app, with the same configs and params pointing to DO pg and I can connect and fetch data etc it works either with local pg installed or with pg uninstalled locally so I am really confused.

On the node server I am using node pg npm package, which works fine on my electron app without the need of a local pg installed.

Please let me know.

Comment: Something is wrong with your config.  Since we can't see it, we can't say what it is.

Comment: @jjanes you mean the config for connection in node pg or some files in the PostgreSQL system folders? Node pg Config is similar to electron app which works really fine. The reason I don’t understand is why is the node server pointing at the local pg even when is uninstalled completely.

Comment: The node or electron config.  You say they are similar, but that is not the same as identical.  If you don't have PostgreSQL server installed and running locally, that doesn't mean you can't attempt to connect to it locally, it just means you can't succeed at that attempt.  Node Pg has its own internal implementation of the PostgreSQL "wire protocol", which means it doesn't need either the PostgreSQL server nor any external client binaries installed to establish (or attempt to establish) connections.

Comment: @jjanes it seems the issue is that my .env variables are not being run properly on my node server while in the elctron app i have them running well, the only difference is that in the electron app i am using doenv package. So the question is do i have to use dotenv package in the node server for the .env variables to be loaded properly?

Answer (score 0):

So the problem was the .env vars not being mounted properly on the data.js configuration, meaning they were not defined and so node pg would automatically try to connect to local pg.

After inserting dotenv package on the data.js it works.